# Using axios-cookiejar-support with Vue.js on the backend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Has anyone used axios-cookiejar-support with Vue.js on the backend?

I'm getting the following error in the Chrome debugger:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: axiosCookieJarSupport is not a function

And when I console.log(axiosCookieJarSupport) I see "undefined" when I run the the init code shown on the axios-cookiejar-support site that modifies Axios to support cookies:

const axiosCookieJarSupport = require('axios-cookiejar-support').default;

axiosCookieJarSupport(axios);  // <--- error occurs here

Obviously, I tried it with a Node.js console application and it works, and I can console.log axiosCookieJarSupport and I see that it is a function in the console application.

I'm guessing I need to somehow tell Webpack (which I believe Vue.js uses) to preload axios-cookiejar-support, as opposed to just include it in the package.json (which I did), but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Did you run "npm install" after adding the line in package.json?

Comment: Yes, I did npm install.
Also, in case it matters, I'm running on Windows 10, and successfully using regular Axios (as opposed to axios-cookiejar-support).

Comment: Here's what I see in the Chrome debugger:Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: axiosCookieJarSupport is not a function
    at Object._callee$ (xyzapi.js?d0b1:17)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?4a57:62)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?4a57:296)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (webpack-internal:///197:114:21)
    at step (asyncToGenerator.js?7b11:17)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?7b11:35)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (_export.js?90cd:36)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?7b11:14)
    at Object.init (xyzapi.js?d0b1:17)

Comment: @MaxKislik Have you resolved this issue? I know it's been a long time but there still doesn't seem to be an answer for it.

Comment: I have not looked into this since 3 years ago, so go ahead and close it